# Why can I only upload files via vsftpd if folders are chmod 777?

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, chmod, vsftpd

I have a problem with vsftpd on Debian: I can upload files if the chmod of all folders is 777, but with chmod 755.

Please help.

vsftpd.conf:

```
local_umask=022
anon_umask=0755
file_open_mode=0755
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the user you're logging in as has no ownership rights of the folder you're accessing.

FWIW 777 isn't neccessary as you don't need execute (just read/write)

You could possibly put the ftp user in the same group as the owner then `chmod g+rw` or you could `chown -R ftpfolder ftpuser.ftpuser` but consider the potential implications of other users that may need access.

Comment: that was exactly the issue. tnx!

Comment: Great! BTW please mark this answer as accepted so it is removed from the unanswered question list. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work